# Как выбрать все подклассы родительского класса в css?

Tags: css

Есть такой небольшой код:

```
<div class="tagcloud">
    <a href="http://coupons-aliexpress.com.ua/coupon_tag/10" class="tag-link-1" title="1 запись" style="font-size: 8pt;">первый</a>
    <a href="http://coupons-aliexpress.com.ua/coupon_tag/11" class="tag-link-2" title="1 запись" style="font-size: 8pt;">второй</a>
    <a href="http://coupons-aliexpress.com.ua/coupon_tag/80" class="tag-link-3" title="1 запись" style="font-size: 8pt;">третий</a>
</div>
```

Нужно в CSS выбрать все подклассы класса `tagcloud` и назначить им одно свойство. Как это сделать?

Что прописать вместо знаков вопроса (`.tagcloud ??? {}`), чтобы свойство назначилось всем подклассам (`tag-link-1`, `tag-link-2` и т.д.)?

Comment: лучше добавить класс `tag` на ссылки и проблема уйдет сама собой

Answer (score 5):

Может так?

```css
.tagcloud [class^='tag-link-']{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagcloud">
    <a href="http://coupons-aliexpress.com.ua/coupon_tag/10" class="tag-link-1" title="1 запись" style="font-size: 8pt;">первый</a>
    <a href="http://coupons-aliexpress.com.ua/coupon_tag/11" class="tag-link-2" title="1 запись" style="font-size: 8pt;">второй</a>
    <a href="http://coupons-aliexpress.com.ua/coupon_tag/80" class="tag-link-3" title="1 запись" style="font-size: 8pt;">третий</a>
</div>
```

Подробнее [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/attr3).

Comment: Спасибо!! Оперативно помогли!

Comment: @Sven, рад, отметьте ответ как верный, пожалуйста.